# Scanning rows with fscanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I want to scan datas from the file to structures with this code, but it scans only the first row to t[0].xy, and nothing or just trash to the others.

```
   int main(void) {
        srand(time(NULL));

        typedef struct Questions {
            char question[150];
            char a[100];
            char b[100];
            char c[100];
            char d[100];
            int difficulty;
            char good;
            char type[20];
        } Questions;

        int row=15;
        Questions t[15];

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("proba.txt", "r");

        for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            fscanf(fp, " %ld ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %[^;] ; %c; %[^\n] \n", 
    &(t[i].difficulty), t[i].question, t[i].a, t[i].b, t[i].c, t[i].d, 
    &(t[i].good),  t[i].type);
        }
        fclose(fp);

        for(int i=0; i<row; i++) {
            printf("%s\nA:%s\nB:%s\nC:%s\nD:%s\n", t[i].question, t[i].a, t[i].b, t[i].c, t[i].d);
            printf("\nCorrect: %c", t[i].good);
        }
    }
```

(One example row from the file: 1;Who was Albert Einstein?;a dog;a cat;a human;a car;C;ANATOMY. Ends with \n. There are no warnings)

Comment: Instead of scanning `15` "*rows*", do it `while (fscanf(file, format, ...) == 7)`.

Comment: @user3121023 fscanf() will read upto space So provide the spaces b/w entities in input files

Comment: I edited the code, now working!  The only modification was that I made a type[20] string in the structure, and put it in the fscanf.